# How to call a function defined in a kernel module (LKM) from kernel code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am newbie on Kernel Development techniques. I was wondering if there is a way to establish communication between Kernel and Kernel Modules (LKM), once Kernel Modules are dynamically loaded. What I want to do is to call a function from a specific part of the Kernel to send some data, while the kernel module is waiting for it. If the module isn't loaded yet, I was thinking it would cause some trouble because the function isn't yet defined too. So my question is, there is a way of calling a function defined on kernel module from somewhere on the kernel? I couldn't find any sources for this question, so I also wanted to ask you if what I'm trying to do is a bad practice and if there's another way of doing this.

This is what I am trying to do:

- I have a function on my LKM called "foo (mesg)"
- I wish to call this function "foo" inside "arch/x86/mm/fault.c" code
- The purpose is to store these "mesgs" and then collect them in user-space using /proc. That's why I am building a LKM.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, there is a way of calling a function defined on
>   kernel module from somewhere on the kernel?

You can do it by creating a callback function in your module and call it using its address.
You need to create a function that receives and locally stores a method pointer in `arch/x86/mm/fault.c` and export it using `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, lets call it "init_foo(void* fn_ptr)".

In your module, create your callback function and call `init_foo` to [pass its address](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/). Now when ever you want to call your callback function just check to see if you have its address `first (!= null)`, if so, then use it to invoke your callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call functions directly from the user space to the kernel module (like with libc calls and unless your kernel module implements a new system call). However, you can call any function implemented within the kernel or another module which has been exported. (EXPORT_SYMBOL()).

Its best if you are more specific on what your kernel module does, if you intend to get more help.

Comment: So, I have changed a specific part of the code "arch/x86/mm/fault.c" where I placed a function "foo(mesg)". I want to implement my LKM with this function "foo" defined there in order to every "mesg" received, I store it in a data structure. The LKM will have an interface with a Daemon using the /proc in order to externalize the collected data to user-level. I couldn't figure out where to insert "EXPORT_SYMBOL" and it'd work.

Comment: @Vinicius `EXPORT_SYMBOL(foo)` should follow immediately after the function definition. Look at how other symbols are exported in the code for examples.